Using google cloud speech-to-text api for real-time speech recognition in dart, flutter
We have tried many libraries like speech-to-text, record and mic_stream. But we did not meet our expectations. I want to recognize the speech continuously and from byte code it will convert to  text every 2 seconds via Google's real-time speech to text api (https://speech.googleapis.com/v1p1beta1/speech:recognize)
I want to use Google's real-time speech to text api(https://speech.googleapis.com/v1p1beta1/speech:recognize) in a flutter project, written in dart.
I have used Speech to text for this but it does not work as per my requirement.
I want the code which works in android and IOS and voice recognize should be continues until I stop and in the return byteArray we will convert it to the text via Google's real-time speech to text api.
I want to develop speech to text app using this API
Please help me out with this and give your suggestions

Were you able to achieve this? Can you help me with the code?
